# Volvo s60 Engine Service Required

Tags: engine, volvo, vacuum

Engine Service Required message has just came up on the LCD and I'm wondering what could be the problem. My known issues are:

- I have the popping noise in the engine and I've tried the same thing as the man on the video and it looks like the hydraulic engine mountings are leaking vacuum ([link to youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHLyubTrIQ8&t=1s)).
- Recently I've got two codes (P0108 and P0401) in Torque lite (with chinese OBDII bluetooth reader). So the problem could also be in EGR or MAF sensor?
- I think that this issue is not connected to these ones, but anyhow. When engine is hot, **sometimes** it won't start properly. It is very similar to this problem ([link to youtube video](https://youtu.be/2425RNslRd4?t=24)). But I think it can't be starter problem, because problem would also occur when engine is cold. Or am I wrong? I also saw that there is urgent to repair crankshaft position sensor. Could this be the issue of this problem?

Sometimes I can feel car to shake just a little bit every 3 seconds when idle. It has a lot of vibrations at 1400 - 1600 rpm in any gear and pretty load resonance sound when over 3000 rpm. I have also seen that fuel consumption has increased for about 0.8 l/100km.

Car doesn't produce any kind of smoke.

car: Volvo s60 2.4D 2004 (401.000 km)

Comment: Given the age of the vehicle I would clean the MAP, and EGR, and run treatment through the tank and intake. See if those codes persist. As far as the vacuum lines, at this age I would just replace them. Other than elbows and fittings, hose is going to be cheap and easy. Check working for signs of damage. Obligatory cleaning of grounds and battery terminals suggested, if you haven't kept up with them.

Comment: This is definitely what I am going to do at first stage. But do you think that vacuum lines could leak? I don't have any "jitter" or rich rpm at idle. Do you have any idea why would it have starting issues?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @spaceman when you're prepared to change the vacuum lines, take them between your fingers and squish and roll. If they hard and/or spongy, then it's very likely they're no good anymore. They should feel soft and supple, have a good elasticity to them, and  return to shape immediately. The fittings and elbows are the only concern as they get brittle, so use care with those. If you plan on keeping the car, I'd replace the vacuum lines regardless. Too many possible issues. The EGRV clogged would cause starting and running issues. Depends on how it's stuck/sticking.

Comment: Thanks NitrusInc. Actually Im planning to work on the car, because I want to have it for a long time, thats why replacing the lines or any other thing is not such big deal for me. Ill try to replace them in few days and will come back with answers. Does maybe you ring a bell what could be the issue with starting problems?